# Make POST requests from Superfeedr on localhost

Tags: java, superfeedr

I want to subscribe to a feed using [Supefeedr](https://superfeedr.com/subscriber).

I have server running on my laptop. So, I just want to know how can I make Superfeedr to POST HTTP requests on my local server using a webhook. I am using Java as my base language.
I just want to test how Superfeedr works. So can anyone help me with that?
I have very less knowledge about  [PubSubHubbub](https://pubsubhubbub.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pubsubhubbub-core-0.4.html) protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is a common problem with webhooks: they only work if your 'listening' server is available outside the firewall. If you deploy on your local machine, you can either simulate the calls from a local HTTP client (like Curl), or use a tool to expose your local port(s) to the web.

There are multiple solutions, including [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), [passageway](https://www.runscope.com/docs/passageway), [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/), [Forwardhq](https://forwardhq.com/) and more I'm sure!

Finally, you could also do that with ssh tuneling if you own a server that's already available to the outerweb as explained in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31226/how-can-i-tunnel-through-an-ssh-server-for-https-requests).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the localtunnel.me utility; it gives you a publicly-accessible URL that forwards to a local machine and is great for testing postbacks and Web hooks.